# Handling staleelement reference exception Coverfox website using Python pytest selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pytest, ui-automation

*content of `test_homepage.py`*

```py
    def test_insurance_pages_open_successfully_using_fixtures(page_object, load_home_page, insurance_data):
            page_object.open_insurance(insurance_data)
            assert page_object.ui.contains_text('Buying two-wheeler insurance from Coverfox is simple')
```

*`open_insurance` function in page object `home_page.py`*

```py
    def open_insurance(self, insurance):
        self._ui.move_to(locators.drp_dwn_insurance)
        self._ui.click(format_locator(locators.lnk_insurance, insurance))
```

*`move_to` function in another `file.py`*

```py
    def move_to(self, locator):
        to_element = self.find_element(locator)
        print("element value", to_element)
        self.action.move_to_element(to_element).perform()
```

What I am trying to over here is 
`test_insurance_pages_open_successfully_using_fixtures` takes 3 fixtures as arguments **1**.

`page_object` that provides a page object at a session-level **2**.

`load_home_page` to load the home page again at session-level  **3**.

`insurance_data fixture` in `conftest.py` which suppliers list of link texts read from some CSV file

So, in essence, it will load the page and open all links one by one for website - https://www.coverfox.com/

First test case passes for link Two-wheelers insurance but for 2nd test data run it fails giving an exception of stale element reference on the point where it is trying to **move to(`move_to` function)** insurance link again.

I am not storing elements anywhere and function is written in a way that it will find the element again.

What is causing this? Or Pytest does some sort of element caching in the background

Comment: Could you please share the Exception?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should use function-level `fixture` for `load_home_page` or refresh the page after you have done some actions.

In the current approach (at least how you described it) you are using the same page and page state for different tests.

Could you please share the fixtures code as well?

Comment: I have tried both ways but it did not work. In one I made load_home_page as a function leve fixture. In another attempt I did it module level only.
Even the way function has been written it is doing a fresh find element with in the function body, ideally exception should not appear

Comment: Yes, please find the exception
E       selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
E         (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
E         (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)

..\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:192: StaleElementReferenceException
=========================================================== 1 failed, 1 passed, 3 skipped in 29.13 s

Comment: fixtures code - 
@pytest.fixture(params=load_test_data("insurance_categories"))
def insurance_data(request):
    data = request.param
    return data